# How to remove Gallium drivers and install default drivers on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: drivers, graphics, display-resolution, gallium

I've tried many methods (removing x.org drivers, ati drivers)...but still I cannot find the x.org file in etc/x11/ ..to make any modification.. My current graphic card is ATI Radeon Hd6670 2GB DDR3..Also I cannot select any other drivers form "Software Updates"..Other drivers are disabled..My resolution is set to 800x600 and I am not able to change that too..In system-Info It shows only "Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.5, 256 bits)"..
Thanks in Advance